# Why is this not an exponential distribution?

Tags: probability-distributions, exponential-distribution

On an exercise sheet I found the following question:

You monitor planes landing at an international airport. **X** measures the time intervals between consecutive landings. *Is **X** exponentially distributed (in good approximation)?*

To me it seemed that this is a clear case of an exponential distribution. However, the correct answer, supposedly, is *no*.

Can you explain to me why X is not exponentially distributed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It slightly depends on how busy the airport is, but note

(a) the mode of an exponential distribution is $0$ while (ignoring emergencies) there is usually a substantial gap between planes landing so the first can clear the runway, and

(b) in a busy airport with restricted [landing slots](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Landing_slot) the controllers try to make planes tend to land with close to equal gaps between them to balance efficiency and safety, so a low standard deviation of gaps compared to their average, while an exponential distribution has a standard deviation equal to its average

Comment: Thank you, that makes sense!